# What exactly does the Multiviews options in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling a lot with an access rule that needed to rewrite one piece of URL adding a path.

```
RewriteRule ^(configuration/.+)$ application-server/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

This Rule caused just a blank page on my Joomla site with no error log or messages.
The curious thing is that all other rules I had worked perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^(log/.+)$ application-server/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
RewriteRule ^(monitor/.+)$ application-server/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

in the end, I've found in a forum a suggestion to use the following option:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

That actually solved the issue, however I wonder if there can be any side effects on other Rules when using this option.

Comment: Did you bother to take a look into the documentation? I just ask because you mention no such thing ...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is about Apache content negotiation.

A `MultiViews` search is where the server does an implicit filename pattern match, and choose from amongst the results.

For example, if you have a file called `configuration.php` (or other extension) in root folder and you set up a rule in your htaccess for a virtual folder called `configuration/` then you'll have a problem with your rule because the server will choose `configuration.php` automatically (if `MultiViews` is enabled, which is the case most of the time).

If you want to disable that behaviour, you simply have to add this in your htaccess
`Options -MultiViews`

This way, your rule will be now evaluated because content negotiation is disabled.

### Edit

On some shared hostings, the *negotiation* module might not be enabled. That would give you then a 500 error. To avoid this error, you can, by default, encapsulate the directive in an `IfModule` block.

```conf
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see the culprit now! that's because joomla has also a phisical folder called configuration.

Comment: FWIW, `Options -MultiViews` doesn't result in a 500 error when mod_negotiation is not enabled. It doesn't even result in a 500 error if you try to _enable_ MultiViews (when mod_negotiation is not enabled) - when maybe it should? However, mod_negotiation is a "Base" module - which means it is "compiled and loaded into the server by default", so it is rare for it to not be available, even on a shared server.