# URL rewriting issue with the same starting name of url in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem accessing some URL with the same starting name of url like these:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^sections?$   sections.php   [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^sections/?$   sections.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^sections/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-.]+)/view?$   view_sections.php?id=$1&name=$2   [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^sections/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-.]+)/view/?$   view_sections.php?id=$1&name=$2    [NC,L]
```

The first 2 rules work but the the last 2 don't, it just load the sections.php instead of view sections.php. When I use Wamp it works but when I uploaded online it doesn't work. Is it because of the version of php and apache?

My Wamp version:

**Apache Version :2.4.9**

**PHP Version :5.5.12**

The hosting version:

**Apache version: Apache/2.2.27**

**PHP version: 5.6.14**

If the problem is version issue then what could be the possible solution to make it work in hosting version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sections?$ sections.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^sections/?$ sections.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^sections/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-.]+)/view?$ view_sections.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^sections/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-.]+)/view/?$ view_sections.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks man! it worked! I just inserted this above (Options -MultiViews). By the way can you tell me the use of that line? hehe

Comment: well it is explained here very well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess

Comment: If it worked for you can acknowledge this as an answer by clicking right arrow beside the answer.