# AppServ mod-rewrite does not recognize $ _GET vars

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Recently on a new PC I installed AppServ.

As always, I started developing a script in PHP previously having configured the .htaccess file

This is the situation:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^step/token/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$   step.php?load=page&page=reset-token&token=$1   [L,QSA]
```

**step.php**

```
print_r($_GET)
```

**Test #1**

If I load the URL

http://localhost/mod-rewrite/step.php?load=page&page=reset-token&token=123

This is the output:

```
Array ( [load] => page [page] => reset-token [token] => 123 )
```

**Test #2**

If I load the URL with the desired format

http://localhost/mod-rewite/step/token/123/

The issue

```
Array ( )
```

In **C:\AppServ\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf**

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so Does not start with #

And AllowOverride is All

```
<directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</directory>
```

What can be happening?

Comment: Is the output from test #2 actually from your `step.php` file?

Comment: Yes, step.php is the only php file in that directory

Comment: Do you have any other redirects? You may also need to [disable `MultiViews`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess)

Comment: If I add **Options -MultiViews** in .htaccess, then step.php It does not load anymore, in that case index.php is load

Comment: Ok, that's progress. That means that your rewrite rule is not matching correctly. Is your `.htaccess` file in the `mod-rewrite` directory along with `step.php`?

Comment: Yes, in the folder "mod-rewrite" there are now only 3 files: .htaccess, step.php and index.php

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put to the beginning of .htaccess "Options -MultiViews"

Then restart services

Thanks to @Phil

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.