# XAMPP mod_rewrite object not found error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I want to create friendly url from

http://localhost/shop/categories.php?cat=asd --> 
http://localhost/shop/category/asd

but i always get `Object not found` Error 404 error from apache.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+category/([a-zA-Z]+)$ /shop/categories.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

**categories.php**

```
<?php 
echo $_GET["cat"]; 
?>
```

Tested with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Output url: http://localhost/shop/categories.php?cat=asd (this url is working)

I've only 2 files in the folder shop:

Path:

C:\xampp\htdocs\shop

Files:

- .htaccess
- categories.php

More info:

- mod_rewrite loaded (checked in phpinfo and httpd.conf)
- AllowOverride All in httpd.conf and httpd.xampp.conf

Comment: Disable MultiViews - it often causes problems when what you are trying to rewrite (partially) matches the name of an actually existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable `MultiViews` option, which is enabled by default most of the time (see [this post and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25423722/3181248) on this topic)

Here is how your `/shop/.htaccess` file should look like:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)$ categories.php?cat=$1 [L,NE]
```