# Debug redirect rule doesn't match?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to redirect

> http://localhost/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard

to

> http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard

with this rule, but it doesn't work (tested locally with apache2 server)

```
RewriteRule ^data/([./]+)$ http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/$1 [L,R=308]
```

I have a [working htaccess](https://github.com/perma-id/w3id.org/blob/master/cocoon/.htaccess) for https://w3id.org/cocoon/v1.0

I'd like to add redirect rules for something like

> https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard
>   https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/storage/azure/premiumssd-p4

---

```
root@CECS-030929:/var/www/html/cocoon# cat .htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Turn off MultiViews https://stackoverflow.com/a/25423722/646732
Options -MultiViews

# Directive to ensure *.rdf files served as appropriate content type,
# if not present in main apache config
AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
AddType application/rdf+xml .owl
AddType text/turtle .ttl
AddType application/n-triples .n3
AddType application/ld+json .json

# Turn off mod_security filtering.
# SecFilterEngine Off
# SecFilterScanPOST Off

# Rewrite engine setup
RewriteEngine On

# code 308 permanent redirect, cacheable,
# The request method and the body will not be altered,
# whereas 301 may incorrectly sometimes be changed to a GET method.
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308

# flag https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
# L|last If the rule matches, no further rules will be processed
# NE|noescape Do not convert to hexcode equivalent
# OR Combine rule conditions with a local OR instead of the implicit AND

# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

# Homepage
RewriteRule ^$ https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema [R=308,L]

# make sure we don't have the file or a directory index to serve
# the rest fails to redirect if we do
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Rewrite rule to serve HTML content from the vocabulary URI if requested
# http://localhost/v0.1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v0\.1/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/index.htm [R=308,NE,L]

# http://localhost/v1.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^v1\.0/?$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/index-en.html [R=308,NE,L]

# Rewrite rule to serve JSON-LD content from the vocabulary URI if requested
# curl -H "Accept: application/ld+json" -L http://localhost/v1.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/ld\+json
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.json [R=308,L]

# Rewrite rule to serve RDF/XML content from the vocabulary URI if requested
# curl -H "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://localhost/v0.1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.rdf [R=308,L]

# curl -LH "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://localhost/v1.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.xml [R=308,L]

# Rewrite rule to serve N-Triples content from the vocabulary URI if requested
# curl -LH "Accept: application/n-triples" http://localhost/v1.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/n-triples
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.nt [R=308,L]

# Rewrite rule to serve TTL content from the vocabulary URI if requested
# curl -LH "Accept: text/turtle" http://localhost/v0.1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/turtle
RewriteRule ^v0\.1$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v0.1/ontology/cocoon.ttl [R=308,L]

# curl -H "Accept: text/turtle" http://localhost/v1.0
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/turtle [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/\* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} \*/turtle
RewriteRule ^v1\.0$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl [R=308,L]

# http://localhost/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard
# http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard
# https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard
RewriteRule ^data/([./]+)$ http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/$1 [L,R=308]
```

---

```
# cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^data/([./]+)$ http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/$1 [L,R=308]

# service apache2 reload
 * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2                                                                                       *
# wget http://localhost/cocoon/data/vm/
--2018-10-17 06:09:10--  http://localhost/cocoon/data/vm/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable
2018-10-17 06:09:10 ERROR 406: Not Acceptable.
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Can you show your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: It is in dir `/var/www/html/cocoon`

Comment: Not Acceptable
An appropriate representation of the requested resource /cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard could not be found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: http://localhost/cocoon/data/vm/azure/windows-d11v2promo-standard

Comment: same error, even only left 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rule to this and retest:

```
RewriteRule ^data/.*$ http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/$0 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSA]
```

In your rule's regex `[./]+` only matches 1+ dot or `/` characters.

Comment: no, this one doesn't work. dot is `\.`, and should be $1, not $0, and I think brackets `()` are needed.

Comment: No brackets needed,`$0` represents complete matching string in `RewriteRule` pattern, which will be `/data/<anything>` and we're using back-reference of same in target.

Comment: Ok, must be chrome catching my redirects, [fiddling with it](https://salferrarello.com/chrome-clear-redirect-cache/) for a while to be sure. this also works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
root@CECS-030929:/var/www/html/cocoon/data# cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://35.227.26.187:5000/cocoon_v1.0?subject=https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE,QSA]
```

But I prefer [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s solution, don't want to create another folder/file
for just 2 lines.