# RewriteRule does not work is specific friendly URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

Somehow when I use a specific friendly URL the rewriterule doens't work.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Below my code within the .httaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I try the following URL everything goes fine:

http://localhost/test/test

However when I use the following URL the rewrite doens't happen:

http://localhost/index/test

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try disabling `MultiViews` option. See my answer on this old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess

Comment: That was indeed the solution! Thank you very much!