# Strange URL match behaviour in PHP on Apache

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

### TL;DR

If I have a `/campaign.php` file `/campaign/some-url-stuff` matches it instead of using the rewrite rule in `.htaccess`

---

I was just making a script for an easter campaign and called it `campaign.php` I set it up to handle a `GET` parameter `name` so sample URL: `https://localhost/campaign.php?name=Easter2021`

Then I went to my `.htaccess` file (apache 2.4 on windows) and created a line in that:

```
RewriteRule ^campaign/(.+)$ /campaign.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Validating with [this debugger](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) that is was correct to call it with the following URL: `https://localhost/campaign/Easter2021`

Then I added some error handling to my script:

#### MCVE

```php
<?php
$campaignName = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'name',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($campaignName == 'Easter2021') {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    header("content-type text/plain");
    echo "Invalid campaign Requested [$campaignName]";
    print_r($_GET);
}
```

So if my file is called the same as the root of the pretty URL, it seems like it is called instead, and the rule is not matched, which means that I get no `name` GET parameter.
`print_r($_GET);` returns `Array ( )`

But if I rename the file and update my `.htaccess` to this: `RewriteRule ^campaign/(.+)$ /campaignHandler.php?name=$1 [L]`

Then `https://localhost/campaign/sdfdsfsdf` gives `Array ( [name] => sdfdsfsdf )`

And the **question** is: **Why?** and what can I do to avoid this in the future? (there must be some php/apache config to solve this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meditating on the issue, and practicing some Google fu, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess) on SO.
The culprit is [Apache httpd's Multiview](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html#negotiation) feature, which, if there exists no file with the asked for name will look at the basename of the files that exist on the server, and serve one of those instead.

Adding `Options -Multiviews` to the `.htaccess` file solves the issue.

#### Update

You may not have permission to override this setting in a `.htaccess` file. If you do have access to the vhost configuration, check that the `<directory>` `Options` don't have *multiview* in them.