# .htaccess rewrite to uri where filename exists but extension omitted

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running into a odd issue with my .htaccess where its failing to pass it to index.php. With my current rewrite rules, if I go to mysite.com/abc123 it properly redirects to the index.php passing /abc123 to the query string for index.php to process.

However, if I go to mysite.com/test I get a apache Not Found error page. I'm expecting this to go to index.php and pass test as a query string.

If I go to mysite.com/test.php it loads that file just fine as expected.

My file structure looks like this:

```
/
|- index.php
|- test.php
|- .htaccess
```

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "\.(html|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=259200, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `MultiViews` from `Options`.

Or if you cannot find where the `Options` directive is located, you can just add this:

```
Options -MultiViews
```