# .htaccess rewrite rule adds .php extension to URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have an apache2 PHP server with the following .htaccess file in the public html root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It contains a RewriteRule in order to redirect URLs like this :

- http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

However we noticed that when a client requests URLs without using the www subdomain, the server redirects to the https/www URL but adds .php extension at the end of the URLs like this :

- http://example.com/page -> https://www.example.com/page.php
- https://example.com/page -> https://www.example.com/page.php

This does not happen when requesting the url using the www subdomain :

- http://www.example.com/page -> https://www.example.com/page

So I figured the web server was adding the file extension to the URLs because of that RewriteRule in the .htaccess.

Can someone help me edit my .htaccess file so the redirection stops adding .php file extension at the end of URLs ? By the way, server is behind Cloudflare proxy. Thanks !

Here is the .conf file :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName {domain.com}
     ServerAlias www.{domain.com}
     ServerAdmin webmaster@{domain.com}
     DocumentRoot /var/www/{domain.com}/public_html

     <Directory /var/www/{domain.com}/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
     </Directory> 
     #ci-dessous remoteip de cloudflare
     RemoteIPHeader CF-Connecting-IP
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{domain.com}-error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{domain.com}-access.log combined
     RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

#      RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ={domain.com} [OR]
#      RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.{domain.com}
#      RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain.com}/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/{domain.com}/privkey.pem
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    SSLProxyEngine on
    <Location "/blog">
        # Replace with your subdomain, https matters here https://ghost.org/help/apache-subdirectory-setup/
        ProxyPass https://{blog-domain}/blog
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Multiviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423141/what-exactly-does-the-multiviews-options-in-htaccess)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$` - that is an utterly pointless condition.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth splitting up your rewrite rules in order to troubleshoot things a little easier (not tested).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Always use https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Always use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove the need for .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```